# PHP count array by unique value

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array like the one below, and I would like to count how many times an agentName occurs.

Basically I want to find out how many times `hello@url.com` and `BYE@url.com` are occurring. Awnser for the below should be `hello@url.com` = 3 and `BYE@url.com` = 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text_date] => 2013-12-04 19:27:29
            [name] => hello@url.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text_date] => 2013-12-07 19:18:32
            [name] => hello@url.com
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text_date] => 2013-12-08 09:59:30
            [name] =>  hello@url.com
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text_date] => 2013-12-04 12:23:24
            [name] => BYE@url.com
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text_date] => 2013-12-04 13:10:18
            [name] => BYE@url.com
        )
)
```

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: `foreach` Please demonstrate some effort before you ask a question. If you don't know literally anything - there are books available

Comment: the `name` is dynamic so values are constantly changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.5, you could do like this

```
$new_array = array_count_values(array_values($yourarray,'name'));
foreach($new_array as $k=>$v)
{
echo "$k occurred $v times\n";
}
```